# Python - Logic of Not Equal Or - lets all selections pass

Tags: python, logic

I was trying to create "not equal to N or n" to allow for different inputs, and have created a logic that allows all selections to pass.
Is my logic wrong, or my coding?

```
item = input()
if item != "N" or item != "n":
    print("Inside loop - {0} not like N or n".format(item))
else: print("outside loop - {0}  like N or n".format(item))
```

Comment: Not sure if the logic or the coding is wrong, but one of the two is wrong. I think you meant `if item != 'N' and item != 'n'` which is equivalent to `if not (item == 'N' or item 'n')` ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little of both -- your `or` isn't testing "not equal to N or n", it's testing "(not equal to N) or (not equal to n)".  You want something more like:

```
if item not in ("N", "n")
```

or:

```
if item != "N" and item != "n"
```

or maybe just:

```
if item.lower() != "n"
```